# Nested Loop triangle in python

Tags: python-3.x

For my assignment, my prof wants me to write a Python program that prompts the user for an integer and then draws five pictures to the console based on the value of n: a square with sides of length n and four right angle triangles where all sides have length n. The output should read:

```
4444
4444
4444
4444

4
44
444
4444

   4
  44
 444
4444

4444
 444
  44
   4

4444
444
44
4
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def main():
  n = input("Give an integer: ")
  numb = 4
  for i in range(0,4):   
     print(n * 4)    
  pass

  for i in range(0,5):
    for j in range(i):
      print(n, end='')    
    print()
  pass

  for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(i):
      print(n * numb, end='\n')
      numb = numb - 1  
    print()
  pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    main()
```

Which gives the output:

```
4444
4444
4444
4444

4
44
444
4444

4444

444
44

4
```

I've tried using other variables in order to add leading spaces to each iteration but it just gave me errors and am completely stumped at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we should solve the problem for you, but note:

```
print(' '*3+n)
```

will print 3 spaces and then the string in n.